# Is there a way to stop Aspell from suggesting certain words (say, offensive) to incorrect spellings in R?

Tags: r, aspell

I am using the `aspell` function of `utils` package in R to spell check my text. Also I am trying to extract correct words for incorrect words detected by Aspell. But Aspell is suggesting offensive words for some incorrect words. I do not want that. How do I stop Aspell from doing this? Is there a way to remove certain words from Aspell dictionary using R only? This is how I am using Aspell.

```
spelling_mistakes <- aspell(file_location2,"Rd", control = c("--master=en_US"),
                            program = aspell_location)

incorrect_words_list <- spelling_mistakes[, 1]

correct_words_for_incorrect_words <- spelling_mistakes[, 5]
```

Comment: Stop being offended?   But rather obviously: edit your source dictionary externally to remove whatever words are undesired.  Or better, turn off "suggestions."

Comment: I need suggestions. I need some suggestion for the incorrect spelling even if it is wrong but it should not be "offensive". I tried googling how to remove certain words from the source dictionary of aspell but no luck. Whatever I found was too complicated. If you know some way around to remove certain words from the source dictionary, please share. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
badWords <- scan(url("http://www.bannedwordlist.com/lists/swearWords.txt"),
                 what=character(0))
## note that the 'bad' words include "job", and "hit" ... 
clean_words <- setdiff(spelling_mistakes[,5],badWords)
```

You haven't given a reproducible example, so I haven't tested this ...

Note that this will *not* give alternative suggestions.  But it will get you partway there.  The documentation for `aspell` does suggest that you can use alternative dictionaries, but you could read that yourself ... http://wordlist.aspell.net/other-dicts/

See also http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-user/2007-07/msg00004.html